# [python] how the vehilce keep moving, while the if condition doesnot receive any value?

Tags: ros, python2.7, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the following code, i want the robot keep moving up to the time that the if condition gets True. Now the problem is that, when one of the conditions in if, receives no value (ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence), the vehicle does not start moving.how can i define such a condition?

(Note:  min() is generated by another python code and provides value for self.object_1.  when i move the vehicle for far, it does not have value, up to the time that the vehicle gets close to the object.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from find_object_2d.msg import DetectionInfo
from sensor_msgs.msg import LaserScan
from std_msgs.msg import Int32, Float32, String, Time, Int8, Float64
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
import numpy as np
from geometry_msgs.msg import Pose


class object_detection_dist_to_goal():
    def __init__(self):
        self.velocity_publisher = rospy.Publisher('/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size = 1)
        self.distance_to_object_publisher = rospy.Publisher('/distance_to_object', Float64, queue_size = 10)
        rospy.Subscriber('/info', DetectionInfo, self.infocallback)
        rospy.Subscriber('lidar_distance',Pose, self.tfcallback)

        self.move = Twist()
        self.object = Pose()
    def tfcallback(self, msg):
        self.object = msg
        #print(self.object)
        self.object_1 = self.object.position.x
        print("object_1", self.object_1)

    def infocallback(self, msg):
        inlier_id = msg.ids
        self.length = len(inlier_id)

        self.move.linear.x = 0.25 
        if (self.length == 2) and (self.object_1 < 5.4):
            self.move.linear.x = 0.0
            print("vehicle stopped: ", self.move.linear.x)
        self.velocity_publisher.publish(self.move)
        
    def loop(self):
        rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('ontrack_cameralidar', anonymous=False)  #anony=False
    on_track_camer_lidar = object_detection_dist_to_goal()
    on_track_camer_lidar.loop()
```

Sorry, i have provided the other python code that generates the min value. I think i should solve the error here first:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from roslib import message
import rospy
import sensor_msgs.point_cloud2 as pc2
from sensor_msgs.msg import PointCloud2, PointField
import numpy as np
import ros_numpy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Pose

#listener
def listen():
    rospy.init_node('listen', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber("/Filtered_points_x", PointCloud2, callback_kinect)
    

def callback_kinect(data):
    pub = rospy.Publisher('lidar_distance',Pose, queue_size=10)
    data_lidar = Pose()
    xyz_array = ros_numpy.point_cloud2.pointcloud2_to_xyz_array(data)
    print(xyz_array)
    mini_data = min(xyz_array[:,0])
    print("mini_data", mini_data)
    data_lidar.position.x = mini_data  
    pub.publish(data_lidar) 
    print("data_points", data_lidar.position.x)
    height =  int (data.height / 2)
    middle_x = int (data.width / 2)
    middle = read_depth (middle_x, height, data)  # do stuff with middle


def read_depth(width, height, data) :
    if (height >= data.height) or (width >= data.width) :
        return -1
    data_out = pc2.read_points(data, field_names= ('x','y','z'), skip_nans=True, uvs=[[width, height]])
    int_data = next(data_out)
    rospy.loginfo("int_data " + str(int_data))
    return int_data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        listen()
        rospy.spin()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

Here, i have limited the input of the subscriber. i mean when the vehicle is near to the objects, it receives a limited data points, and when i start moving the vehicle far from the objects it does not receive any value and shows the following error:

```
[[ 7.99410915  1.36072445 -0.99567264]]
('mini_data', 7.994109153747559)
('data_points', 7.994109153747559)
[INFO] [1662109961.035894]: int_data (7.994109153747559, 1.3607244491577148, -0.9956726431846619)
[]
[ERROR] [1662109961.135572]: bad callback: <function callback_kinect at 0x7f9346d44230>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 750, in _invoke_callback
    cb(msg)
  File "/home/masoumeh/catkin_ws/src/yocs_velocity_smoother/test4/distance_from_pointcloud.py", line 27, in callback_kinect
    mini_data = min(xyz_array[:,0])
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

Now, my question is that, how can i modify this code, in order to publish data when it receives the input from subscriber?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/405842/%5Bpython%5D-how-the-vehilce-keep-moving,-while-the-if-condition-doesnot-receive-any-value?!/) by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2022-09-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-09-01**:
We do not see any `min` function in your code.

**Comment by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on 2022-09-02**:
min() is generated by another python code and provides value for self.object_1.

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-09-02**:\

> min() is generated by another python code and provides value for self.object_1.

We can not see hidden things. Thus we have no idea what you are saying about. Ideally, you should post the [minimal reproducible example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_reproducible_example) in an online forum but not the entire project. This not only helps you to dig down into the issue but also saves our time.

**Comment by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on 2022-09-02**:
Dear @ravijoshi
i have provided the other python code, and the error relared. would please help me to find the solution?
Thanks in advance

**Comment by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on 2022-09-02**:
Dear @ravijoshi ,
this is the xyz_array:

```
[[ 5.68112087  1.09555054 -0.91642445]
 [ 5.66322517  0.86893958 -0.90752858]
 [ 5.31835747  1.20884693 -0.86386597]]
```

the number of these data points keep changing, i mean it depends to the input.
the error is not resolving, but at least the vehicle starts moving!

Sorry, here you mentioned that: "The snippet you have posted in the answer above, has incorrect indentation. Furthermore, it is using else without using if. It will not run!"

the indentation of which part?? and i have not used "else" in my code, which part you mean??
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. Initialize your `Twist` and `Pose` object before creating subscribers. Therefore you should move the following lines just below `def __init__(self):`

   ```
    self.move = Twist()
    self.object = Pose()
   ```
2. Please initialize `self.object_1` to `None` just below the initialization of the `Twist` and `Pose` objects,

   ```
    self.object_1 = None
   ```
3. Please use the conditional statement  `if (self.length == 2) and (self.object_1 < 5.4):` only after ensuring that `self.object_1` is `not None`.

On a side note, if `lidar_distance` and `/info` topics are running at a similar frequency, you may couple and receive them together in a single callback. Thus your logic will become much cleaner.

### Update

The question has been updated completely. I am not sure if it is good practice to modify it entirely. Never mind, following is the error:

```
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

The error is coming from this line `mini_data = min(xyz_array[:,0])`. So, please check the shape of `xyz_array` before indexing over it.

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2022-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on 2022-09-02**:
@ravijoshi , Thanks a lot for the comment,
just i did not get the point of number 3. how should i write this?
thanks

**Comment by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on 2022-09-02**:
in this way is it True:

```
while (self.object_1 == None):
            self.move.linear.x = 0.25    
        else:
            if (self.length == 2) and (self.object_1 < 5.4):
                self.move.linear.x = 0.0
```

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-09-02**:\

> how should i write this?

I am worried about the `self.object_1` variable. If it is `None` (just think if `/info` topic arrives before `lidar_distance` topic), then your `if` condition will crash the program. The simplest way is to wrap it as shown below:

```
if self.object_1 is not None:
  if (self.length == 2) and (self.object_1 < 5.4):
    self.move.linear.x = 0.0
    print("vehicle stopped: ", self.move.linear.x)
```

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-09-02**:
The snippet you have posted in the answer above, has incorrect indentation. Furthermore, it is using `else` without using `if`. It will not run!

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-09-02**:
Please see the update section under the answer. Moreover, you have changed the question entirely. I suggest discussing only one problem in a question. Nevermind, please upvote and mark the answer as accepted if the `ValueError: min()  ...` is fixed.